# LDAP: How to authenticate user with sAMAccountName?

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I am not able to authenticate when user passes `sAMAccountName` and `password`.

If I do follwoing:

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN="+username+",OU=Service Accounts,OU=TECH,DC=wawalab2,DC=ins");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
```

it throws exception:

> javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, vece

```
Note: I can use Spring LDAP framework too.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the 525 error is bad DN.  You can see a list of the LDAP errors AD returns at this link: [AD LDAP Error codes](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/1424/sub-error-codes-ldap-error-49)

So you have a bad DN.  What you want to do is search for samAccountName=username, get the DN from the returned value, and bind with that proper DN.